# Sensitive feature in Fairlearn

Tags: python, fairlearn

I am using the Fairlearn functions similar to this:

```
    eor = fairlearn.metrics.equalized_odds_ratio(y_true, y_pred, sensitive_features=sensitive_feature)

    
    dpd = fairlearn.metrics.demographic_parity_difference(y_true, y_pred, sensitive_features=sensitive_feature)

    
    di = fairlearn.metrics.demographic_parity_ratio(y_true, y_pred, sensitive_features=sensitive_feature)
```

where y_pred is a binary representing the computed predictions, y_true is also binary representing the truth labels, and sensitive_feature  is a binary dataframe consisting of one column of 1's and 0's, for example if measuring the metrics for the  groups young and old, 1 would represent young and 0 would represent old, old is then the protected group. What if young is the protected group? Do then I have to invert the column in my dataframe sensitive_feature and supply it again to the Fairlearn functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairlearn maintainer here!

No, you don't need to change anything. It doesn't matter for the outcome of these functions. For example, demographic parity just looks at y_pred and ignores y_true. Let's say "young" has a selection rate (percentage of 1s) of 0.8 and "old" has a selection rate of 0.6. The demographic parity difference will always be max-min, that is 0.8-0.6=0.2. Even if the other group is the max it's the same outcome. For the ratio, it's min/max, so 0.6/0.8=0.75.

If you have more than 2 groups it'll still work, but it only considers the max and min groups. Any groups in between won't be represented by this particular measure.